# jQuery div or using input field name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a question regarding the input box below. I'm using jQuery to capture 
the input field. Do you need do have a surrounded div or can you use the name attribute from the html form tag?

```
<input type="text" name="name" size="30">
```

and

```
var MIN_LENGTH = 3;
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#keyword").keyup(function() {
                var keyword = $("#keyword").val();
                if (keyword.length >= MIN_LENGTH) {
                    $.get( "auto-complete.php", { keyword: keyword } )
                        .done(function( data ) {
                                console.log(data);
                            });
                }
            });

    });
```

what's the right way of doing it?

Comment: So use an attribute selector. https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: add an id attribute to your input  like so: `id="keyword"` since you are selecting `#keyword` in jquery

Answer (score 2):

You are asking how to select the element by name and not id? Use the [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
$('[name="name"]').keyup(function() {
    var keyword = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To select elements in the DOM with JQuery you can use ID, CSS Class or any attribute of the element. So if you don't want to add an ID for that element you can select it by the name attribute.

```
var $nameElement = $("[name='name']");
```

And for your block you can do:

```
var MIN_LENGTH = 3;

$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';

  var autocompleteKeywords = function autocompleteKeywords() {
    var keyword = $(this).val();
    if (keyword.length < MIN_LENGTH) return;
    console.log("Searching Keyword: " + keyword); 
    $.get('auto-complete.php', {
      keyword: keyword
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  };

  var setupKeywordField = function setupKeywordField() {
    $('#keyword').on('keyup', autocompleteKeywords);
  };

  setupKeywordField();
});
```

Like in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ndpd32x5/

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
 $("input[name='name']").keyup(function() {
    var keyword = $(this).val();
    // more implementation
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

No you don't. Using jquery you should target the input by its id (after adding and id attribute to the input)

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="30">
```

then get its vale like:

```
var value = $("#name").val()
```